# how to store json values into array with php?

Tags: php, arrays, json

I Need to push in a array all the values of "total_value" and all the values of "car_id" that came form a json url.

Json:

```
[
  {
    "control": {
      "color": "blue",
      "total_value": 21.5,
      "car_id": 421118
    }
  },
  {
    "control": {
      "color": "green",
      "total_value": 25,
      "car_id": 421119
    },
  {
    "control": {
      "color": "red",
      "total_value": 18,
      "car_id": 421519
    }
}
]
```

My Php:

```
<?php

$getJson = file_get_contents("http://url.com/control.json",false);

$j = json_decode($getJson);
```

Comment: Does `$j = json_decode($getJson,true);` (add true as second value) help?

Comment: maybe, but then? how I store the values in diferent arrays?

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: an array with the "total_value" and another array with the "car_id"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your json is not properly formatted, you are missing an `}`

You could loop your `$j` and get the values like `$item->control->total_value`.
Then add the 2 values you are looking for to an array and add the array to the `$result`.

```
$j = json_decode($data);
$result = [];
foreach ($j as $item) {
    array_push($result,[
        'total_value' => $item->control->total_value,
        'car_id' => $item->control->car_id
    ]);
}
```

[Php output example](https://3v4l.org/Wqh8g)

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
$result = [];
foreach ($j as $item) {
    array_push($result, [
        'total_value' => $item['total_value'],
        'car_id' => $item['car_id']
    ]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also achieve this using [array_walk()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk.php) and removing the item you don't want, this is a shorter amount of code and does not require you to create temporary variables or start with an object and end up with an array.

```
array_walk($obj, function(&$v, $k) {
    unset($v->control->color);
});
```

**So for example *(fixing your broken json)*:**

```
<?php
$json = '[{
        "control": {
            "color": "blue",
            "total_value": 21.5,
            "car_id": 421118
        }
    },
    {
        "control": {
            "color": "green",
            "total_value": 25,
            "car_id": 421119
        }
    },
    {
        "control": {
            "color": "red",
            "total_value": 18,
            "car_id": 421519
        }
    }
]';

$obj = json_decode($json);

array_walk($obj, function(&$v, $k) {
    unset($v->control->color);
});

print_r($obj);
```

https://3v4l.org/hXada

**Result:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [control] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [total_value] => 21.5
                    [car_id] => 421118
                )

        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [control] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [total_value] => 25
                    [car_id] => 421119
                )

        )

    [2] => stdClass Object
        (
            [control] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [total_value] => 18
                    [car_id] => 421519
                )

        )

)
```